# Insert single column return value into multiple columns of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a db setup like below

```
create table children_A (
  id serial primary key,
  value text not null
);

create table children_B (
  id serial primary key,
  value text not null
);

create table parent_C (
  id serial primary key,
  child_A_id int not null,
  child_B_id int not null
);
```

and I have an insert query like

```
 with
  children_A_insert as (  -- upsert in children_A and return id
    insert into children_A(value)
    values ('John')
    on conflict (value)
    do nothing
    returning id
  ),
  children_B_insert as ( -- upsert in children_B and return id
    insert into children_B(value)
    values ('Terry')
    on conflict (value)
    do nothing
    returning id
  )

-- insert into parentC(child_A_id, child_B_id) how to write this insert and select query ??
select children.id as id  -- how can I trasnlate returning array of intergers into different columns for parent_C table
from (
  select id from children_A_insert  -- either get newly inserted id
  union all
  select id from children_A where value = 'John'  -- or get the existing id from the children table
  union all
  select id from children_B_insert
  union all
  select id from children_B where value = 'Terry'
)
```

which essentially a query to insert into multiple tables in a single sql command.
result of the query is something like

```
   id
---------
   10
   12
```

the problem is I want to take `children.id as id` and insert the returning ids into the parent table like

```
   id
---------
   10
   12
```

should get trasnlated to

```
   child_A_id   |    child_B_id
       10       |         12
```

in the parent table. Unfortunately, `id` being a single column can not insert values in `parent_C`'s multiple columns.
Is there a way to use  `children.id` (single column) and insert the values to `parent_C`'s multiple columns.

Comment: `INSERT INTO parent_C(id,child_A_id, child_B_id) SELECT '1234',(select id from children_A_insert  union all  select id from children_A where value = 'John'),(select id from children_A_insert  union all  select id from children_A where value = 'Terry');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must add some constraint in `children_A` table and `children_B` table for upsert. Now to achieve the above insert you can try like below:

```
 with
  children_A_insert as (  
    insert into children_A(value)
    values ('John')
    on conflict (value)
    do
    update set value=EXCLUDED.value
    returning id  
),
  children_B_insert as (
    insert into children_B(value)
    values ('Terry')
    on conflict (value)
    do
    update set value=EXCLUDED.value
    returning id
  )

insert into parent_c (child_A_id,child_B_id) 
values((select id from children_A_insert), 
(select id from children_B_insert))
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1aad95443dd1e596b8ed8ddea13fc111)

NOTE: Above will work if you are inserting only one value in each table at a time

Comment: thank you !
is there a way to get `parent id`? I can get the newly inserted id from `returning id` but what if the row already exists in the parent table and nothing got inserted that time the `retrning id` = `null`.

Comment: in that case you have to use `Do Update` instead of `Do Nothing`. if you use `Do Nothing` then it will return `NULL` in case of conflict. I have updated the answer accordingly. Let me know in case of any clarification

Comment: `Above will work if you are inserting only one value` - could you hint me how to insert multiple values at a time.